# plotting graphs when rownames and column names are not identical

Tags: r

I tried everything and I could not find any meaningful answers so I decided to post this here. I have an adjacency matrix as shown below

I am trying to create a plot of a simple graph

```
library(graph)
g = as(x4, "graphNEL")
plot(g, "neato")
```

I got an error message

```
Error in asMethod(object) : 'rownames(from)' and 'colnames(from)' must be identical


                           Abdominal pain Chest pain Flu-like Liver Damage Nausea Numbness Swelling
           Avandaia                  1          0        0            1      1        1        1
           Warfrin                   0          1        1            0      1        1        1
           Flu-like                  0          0        0            0      0        0        0
           Liver Damage              0          0        0            0      0        0        0
           Nausea                    0          0        0            0      0        0        0
           Numbness                  0          0        0            0      0        0        0
           Swelling                  0          0        0            0      0        0        0
```

Any advice would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Try `rownames(g) <- colnames(g)` then plot, does it work?

Comment: @zx8754 tired that, still getting same error

Comment: Assuming that `x4` is your adjacency matrix, try setting `rownames(x4) <- colnames(x4)`, then create and plot `g`.

Answer (score 0):

jlhoward when I do  rownames(x4) <- colnames(x4) I am making my rownames and column names the same, I am interested in a graph when row names and column names are not equal.